# A woman's singing voice when there are other singing voices

Tags: sources-mekorot, song-poetry, music, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, kol-isha

There is a famous Teshuva of the Sridei Aish, Rabbi Yaakov Yechiel Weinberg, that permits one to hear kol isha (a women's singing voice) when there are other people singing.

Where is this Teshuva exactly? Is it if even a number of women are singing or only if it's a woman's voice together with a man's voice?

Comment: more general: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78779

Answer (score 3):

The source is Seridei Esh 2:8, as you can see from [this](http://ph.yhb.org.il/09-06-12/) Hebrew page and from [this](http://koltorah.org/ravj/The%20Parameters%20of%20Kol%20Isha.htm) English one. Regrettably, I have been unable to find the teshuva online. The best I can offer you is [this](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/ishut/ishut22.htm) source, which contains the expurgated text of the teshuva, with the relevant halakhic material removed.

Comment: page 21 here http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?174341& (in the free preview) but the last paragraph is missing due to a technical glitch.

Comment: I have the original and could scan the end if relevant to anyone