# What to do if mother-in-law is singing at meal?

Tags: halacha, shabbat-songs, kol-isha

How should one act halachically if he invites not so observant female family members (specifically mother in law) at the shabbat table and they start singing.

Comment: There's no issue of *kol isha* by *d'varim shebikdusha* FWIW.

Comment: @Scimonster what you mean by devarim sheb'. even shabbat zemirot?

Comment: Yeah. But of course if they start singing secular stuff it might be different.

Comment: I assume there would be a distinction between one's mother (for example) and one's mother in law.

Comment: @Scimonster I wouldn't call it "no issue." At most, I would say there are some who permit.

Comment: There are lots of opinions about what kind of female voice usage is prohibited for various people to interact with in various ways. Please specify accd to what opinion your question is (ie precisely what is forbidden for whom) in order to best figure out how to avoid that prohibition. Also, worth sourcing your position.

Comment: @DoubleAA simple case. mother in law sings at shabbat table. what to do.

Comment: @ray How is that simple? What is asur? I don't understand. Sing along and enjoy your Shabbat. I don't know how anyone can answer this when you haven't even formulated the scope of this alleged prohibition. Unbinding VTC as unclear.

Comment: http://revivim.yhb.org.il/2012/01/09/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%94/

Comment: @cham If by "they" you mean the Y'rei'im, et al., they didn't permit listening to non-Jewish women singing. They said that a person does not have to stop their Torah learning if they are within earshot. I suppose that's relevant to this question insofar as there is a difference between listening and hearing; if a mother-in-law singing *z'miros* is *kol isha*, there are more options besides either listening for enjoyment or fleeing the room in apparent terror (e.g. staying in the room for *shalom bayis*, but not focusing on or actively trying to listen to one's mother-in-law singing).

Comment: I did delete the comment @fred. Instead I linked a long article discussing this. I must though disagree with you. This was a 'special' heter which should not really have been allowed. It was only allowed because otherwise people would not be able to learn. I think for sholom bayis it should also be allowed. I dont think the heter there was because they were just hearing and not listening. It is usually very difficult to accomplish this especially someone with a good voice.

Comment: @cham Of course, but it is possible that this would be allowed for *shalom bayis* or other considerations so long as לא קא מיכוין ליהנות. I totally disagree with you about saying that any heter would extend to allowing one to intend to focus on or enjoy the singing. Furthermore, the reason that special heter was required for hearing a woman sing is that *erva* prevents one from being allowed to learn Torah. If a person is not learning Torah (or praying or reciting *sh'ma'*) at the time, a special heter for incidentally hearing a woman sing is unnecessary.

Comment: Do you live in a context where women sing songs like this generally?

Comment: @Scimonster do you have a Mekor that allows d'var shevikdusha? there is nothing wrong with a chazanit?

Comment: @Emilios1995 See the Chida in Nachal Kedumim Beshallach 14. As well worth reading the commonly cited but oft caricatured responsum of the Seridei Eish on the matter. Note that most Rishonim had no Kol Isha qualms with women Leining (interpret that as you may).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do. Just don't pay attention to her voice (assuming, for the sake of the question, that your Rov holds kol isha is forbidden even for Shabbos zemiros). If you tell her to stop, or even hint, that would be perceived as rude, and it would alienate her from Yiddishkeit and perhaps prevent her from coming closer to observance. If she becomes more observant, she will learn on her own.

This is standard kiruv practice. Can you imagine a Chabad rabbi or rebbetzin telling the women in a Chabad house shul to stop singing? They would never do such a thing, because they know it is counterproductive. Sometimes one has to sacrifice one's own stringency for the sake of someone else's growth (The Gutnick Chumash discusses this idea.) (I understand that this is not a matter of a chumra but of different halachic opinions of differing stringency.)

In addition, correcting your mother-in-law in front of your wife is never a good idea, since your wife will likely get angry and take her side. Source for most of the above: the "Fifth Book of the Shulchan Aruch" (Common Sense).

Note that in a similar situation, when in the Israeli army troops had to attend a concert with kol isha, some rabbis (such as Lazer Brody, if I remember correctly) advised religious soldiers to simply tune it out and ignore it rather than getting up and leaving and thus causing a scene.

I would make an exception to the above advice for someone who is reasonable certain they can mention the issue (perhaps not on Shabbos or if it comes up in conversation) so that she learns about kol isha, without offending her or alienating her from Judaism. If that is the case, then he could do so.

If your rabbi holds that this type of kol isha should be avoided at all costs, regardless of other considerations, then don't invite them, or find a polite way to inform her about kol isha. An intermediate alternative would be to sing wordless niggunim or songs without pesukim, to avoid reciting pesukim in the presence of ervah.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't start songs? Maybe you should start nay-nay-nay-ing instead of saying words of pesukim? Maybe you should let your wife get angry and divorce her (w/o Ketuba) if she continues violating Das Yehudis? Maybe you shouldn't invite your in-laws over?

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, your mother-in-law is a reasonable person and actually respects her son-in-law has his way of Judaism and she'll listen to you in your presence?

Comment: Well, many poskim permit one to invite nonobservant Jews to a Shabbos meal even if they would drive, because the special ambiance of a Shabbos meal often brings people closer to Yiddishkeit. Since singing is part of the typical Shabbos meal experience, then according to that logic, perhaps one should start singing even if the female guests will sing audibly. I don't understand why a wordless niggun would be preferable. I think it's obvious that following the most stringent kol isha opinion is not worth divorcing or ruining Shalom Bayis over.

Comment: "I don't understand why a wordless niggun would be preferable." You can't say pesukim in front of Ervah. Despite some modern sensibilities, there are plenty of ways of having a nice Shabbos meal without songs. I might think it's obvious that the referenced Kol Isha opinion isn't worth following ever, but the case here in the question assumes you got a psak that it's assur. "many poskim permit" is that the case in the OP's case?

Comment: Even if she respects him and his Judaism then she could still be offended and turned off. But if he is reasonable sure it would not push her away then it could be OK to mention it sometime so she learns. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: @DoubleAA There are also *z'miros* (with words) that don't quote *p'sukim*, and some of those *z'miros* probably can't count as Torah learning at all.

Comment: @Fred Indeed. Perhaps those should be chosen. This answer's not even mentioning that option is rather weak, though to be fair the OP never specified what his issue with the singing was.

Comment: Even if one gets the psak that it's assur, the existence of other more lenient opinions, particularly for group singing of religious songs, is a good reason to be lenient for the sake of kiruv and shalom bayis. I assumed for the sake of the question that the Rav holds kol isha in collective religious singing to be assur, but not necessarily that the rabbi holds it must be avoided at all costs.) One can believe something is assur in the abstract yet follow a more lenient opinion under extenuating circumstances.

Comment: Since some authorities permit women to sing as part of a group singing a religious song, then forbidding that is a stringent opinion (not a chumra).

Comment: @Kordovero Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29378.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin What is forbidden due to the Talmudic dictum קול באשה ערוה is a matter of rabbinic debate, as you know. As with most rabbinic debates, there are more stringent and more lenient understandings, and there are always those who may advocate being stringent on a given issue only as a matter of what's colloquially known as "chumra". (Pretty sure you knew all that, actually. Perhaps your comment was a disingenuous way of critiquing the lenient positions as invalid?)

Comment: @Kordovero Certainly those are all possibilities. If you would like to make a value judgement in any direction such as that you should be explicit that it is your own personal thoughts on the matter, not a given.

Comment: @DoubleAA No. A "Chumra" means something I'm not Halachically obligated to do. I assume the OP doesn't hold of the "women to sing as part of a group singing a religious song". If he felt that it's OK, then he wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin How do you know he didn't feel it was only discouraged as a Chumra?