# Can a man listen to woman singing a pizmon?

Tags: halacha, song-poetry, shabbat-songs, kol-isha

Hypothetically, would it be permitted for a man to learn a pizmon from a woman? Namely, that she sings a tune for the purpose of teaching Torah (i.e. Tehilim) and the man has the intent to learn. Does it fulfill the parameters of *kol isha*?

Comment: See the Sredei Eish 2:8 which may give leneicey to zemiros (kedusha type singing). However, many argue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do if mother-in-law is singing at meal?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59210/what-to-do-if-mother-in-law-is-singing-at-meal)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29378/16706

Comment: Why are there votes to close as asking for a practical ruling on a question that begins with the word "hypothetically"?